# How to set permissions (like allow-edit permission, allow-print permission with a password) of pdf document in python code

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I need to set permissions of the PDF document when using python to generate a PDF file. Permissions like `allow-edit` permission, `allow-print` permission with a *password*, taht you can see under `Adobe Acrobat security options` (see pictures). Currently I just am using `PyPdf2` to set a viewing password for the file, but I also need to request that the viewers can't modify this document, even if they has the opening password.

How can I implement this?

[image: Adobe Acrobat security option 1]
[image: Adobe Acrobat security option 2]

Answer (score 1):

[PyMuPDF](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF) appears to have the ability to edit document permissions.
See here: [document-permissions](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vars.html#document-permissions).

Comment: it's no longer available